# Applying custom image processing filters in Xamarin for iOS and Android

Tags: c#, ios, bitmap, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I'm just getting started with Xamarin and I'm trying to build a simple proof of concept that loads an image from the photo gallery and then "does something" with the pixels. This isn't really a use case for a built-in filter; I need to look at every pixel individually and run some business logic based on that and output some results.

The struggle here is on the input side. I have no idea how to retrieve individual pixel color data from a CGImage or CIImage on the iOS side of Xamarin, whereas Android has GetPixel. I guess I am looking for something to loop through in iOS like in CLR System.Drawing bitmaps.

Secondly, can I do this in a cross-platform way? Is there some common type that I can create reliably from a CGImage on iOS and a Bitmap on Android? Then I could just pass that structure to my core library, let it do the work in a platform agnostic way, and return my POCO containing results.

Thanks in advance.
Dan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597198/retrieving-a-pixel-alpha-value-for-a-uiimage-monotouch) has an in-depth response about getting the values of individual pixels using Xamarin.iOS (MonoTouch).

To do this in a platform agnostic way, you would probably need to create a BMP from the Image on each platform and then pass that to your library.

Comment: Thanks for that, this looks really promising. When you say create a BMP, are you referring to a Mono bitmap of some kind or a System.Drawing.Bitmap? (Sorry, super new to both Mono and Xamarin, thanks for your help.)

Comment: I was thinking generic bitmap, just a byte array.  I don't think iOS has a native BMP format you can write to.  This question may help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1350654/how-do-i-save-an-uiimage-as-bmp